# Inserting values into HashMap not functioning properly

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to insert values of a `String` and `ArrayList<String>` into a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`. The code in the for loop works fine but it does not insert the values that I wanted when inserting ArrayList values into the HashMap.

My code:

```
  for(int i=0; i<fileNames.length; i++)
  {
    File imageFile = new File(fileNames[i]);
    metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(imageFile);

    String[] results;
    container.clear();
    println(container);

    for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories())
    {
      for (Tag tag : directory.getTags())
      {
        if(tag.getTagName() == "Keywords")
        {
          results = tag.getDescription().split(";");

          for(int k=0; k<results.length; k++)
          {
            keywords.add(results[k]);
            container.add(results[k]);
          }
          println(fileNames[i] + ", " + container);
          imageTag.put(fileNames[i], container);
        } 
      }
    }
  }

  println(imageTag.entrySet());
}
```

which prints out:

```
[]
gardensbythebay.jpg, [gardens, gardens by the bay, supertree, singapore]
[]
mbs.jpg, [marina, bay, sands, ferris, wheel, skyline, singapore]
[]
supertree.jpg, [architecture, marina, gardens, bay, tower, supertree, singapore, gardens by the bay, plants, nature]
[]
uss.JPG, [universal, uss, rws, resort, world, sentosa, studios]

[mbs.jpg=[universal, uss, rws, resort, world, sentosa, studios], 
uss.JPG=[universal, uss, rws, resort, world, sentosa, studios], 
supertree.jpg=[universal, uss, rws, resort, world, sentosa, studios], 
gardensbythebay.jpg=[universal, uss, rws, resort, world, sentosa, studios]]
```

Comment: Well you're comparing strings with `==`, which doesn't help - but we don't have nearly enough information to know what you *expected* the result to be (or why) to tell you whether that's the *only* problem.

Comment: what's the problem? Looking the output, everything seems inserted correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You keep reusing the same ArrayList. So when you clear it, it also clears what you previously placed in the map. And when you populate it it populates what is already in the map too. So you end up with all your keys pointing to the same list which contains the data of your last run.

You need to create a new ArrayList for each entry.

Comment: +1 When you put a *reference* to a collection in a HashMap, you are only copying the reference, not the contents. When you reuse the collection, you are using just one ArrayList where all the keys point to the same list.  What you want to do is to create a new ArrayList for each key so they are different lists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug:

```
if (tag.getTagName() == "Keywords")
```

This will **never** be true. You should use:

```
if (tag.getTagName().equals("Keywords"))
```

But your main problem is you are *reusing* the *same* container for each entry. You should create a new one each entry, otherwise you are clearing and adding to *the same* map value over and over.

Answer (score 0):

At each iteration, you're clearing your container, add elements to it, and then add the container to the map.

The map only stores references. It doesn't make a copy of the list. So you end up with all the keys having the same value: the container list, containing what the last iteration added to it.

Each iteration should create a new list, and add this list to the map.